# Changing Kerberos password with PHP

Tags: php, authentication, kerberos

I have a need to create and update user password using Kerberos and my site is PHP. I found a PHP extension which allows this type of interaction, but it is from 2003 and can no longer be compiled due to Kerberos updating since then. 
[Kerberos PHP Extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/kadm5)

I searched for other ways to do this, but I couldn't find any. Does anyone have experience with this?